# How to find the diagonal values of a natural square root number

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the diagonal values of a square number. If I give the number `2`, it should turn that into a square and give the diagonal values:

For `2`

```
[0,1
 2,3]
```

will give `[[0,3],[1,2]]`

or `3`

```
[0,1,2
 3,4,5
 6,7,8]
```

will give `[[0,4,8], [2,4,6]`

or `4`

```
[0 ,1 ,2 ,3
 4 ,5 ,6 ,7
 8 ,9 ,10,11
 12,13,14,15]
```

will give `[[0,5,10,15],[3,6,9,12]]`

etc

```
def diagonal(2)

end
#=> [[0,3],[1,2]]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask for help, you need to show us the code you've been working on. Failing to do so makes it look like you want us to write a solution for you, which isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should post something you've tried before. Anyway, here you go:

```
def diagonal(a)
  [0.step(a**2,a+1).to_a, (a-1).step(a**2-a,a-1).to_a]
end

diagonal 2
#=> [[0, 3], [1, 2]]
diagonal 3
#=> [[0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
diagonal 4
#=> [[0, 5, 10, 15], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Comment: you're a genius. Thank you. Mine was mostly hardcoded around the magic number i needed I needed something scalable. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways you could do this.

**#1**

If speed and memory are not an issue, you could do the following:

```
def diags(n)
  arr = (0...n*n).each_slice(n).to_a
  [diag(arr), diag(rotate(arr))]
end

def rotate(a)
  a.map { |row| row.reverse }
end

def diag(a)
  a.size.times.map { |i| a[i][i] }
end
```

**#2**

The essence of the approach is effectively the same as @Grych's answer, but I would suggest using a helper:

```
def diags(n)
  [vec(n, 0, n+1), vec(n, n-1, n-1)]
 end

def vec(vec_size, start, step_size)
  (start...start+vec_size**2).step(step_size).to_a
end
```

**Examples**

```
(2..4).each do |n|
  w = n.to_s.size + 2
  (0...n**2).each_slice(n) { |a| a.each { |i| print "%#{w}s" % i }; puts } 
  p diags(n)
  puts
end

  0  1
  2  3
[[0, 3], [1, 2]]

  0  1  2
  3  4  5
  6  7  8
[[0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15
[[0, 5, 10, 15], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```